# ¿Cómo quitar el segundo repetido de una cadena sin replace?

Tags: java

Este es mi código pero no me retorna lo que pide el ejercicio:

> Escribir un método `static String sinRepetidos(String s)` que dada una cadena, devuelve
> una nueva cadena donde cada uno de los caracteres que aparecían en s, aparecen solo una vez.
> Se debe mantener la posición relativa de los caracteres: para aquellos que se encuentren repetidos
> puede conservarse cualquiera de sus apariciones. Por ejemplo, para la palabra ‘‘casos’’ puede
> devolver ‘‘caso’’ o ‘‘caos’’, conservando la primera o la segunda letra s respectivamente.

```
public class ejercicio22 {

    static String sinRepetidos(String s) {
        
        String vacio= "";
    
        
        for (int i=0; i < s.length();i++) {
            char letras= s.charAt(i);
            
            for (int ii=1; ii< s.length();ii++) {
                char letras1= s.charAt(ii);
            
                
        if (letras!=letras1  ) {
            vacio=vacio + letras; 
            
                
        
        }
        }
            }
    return vacio;
}
      
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
String a= "abbi";
ejercicio22 llamar= new ejercicio22();
llamar.sinRepetidos(a);
}
}
```

Lo que me imprime es lo siguiente:

`vacio= aaabbii`

¿Qué hago mal?

Answer (score 2):

Sin usar el método `replace` podría ser algo así: 
 Recorre el string con un bucle y verifica si el carácter no está en el resultado:

```
private static String sinRepetidos(String s) {
    String result = "";
    
    for(char letter : s.toCharArray()) {
        if(!result.contains(Character.toString(letter))) {
            result+=letter;
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(sinRepetidos("casos"));
    System.out.println(sinRepetidos("abbi"));
    System.out.println(sinRepetidos("mini"));
    System.out.println(sinRepetidos("otorrinolaringólogo"));
}
```

Salida:

```
caso
abi
min
otrinlagó
```